# Can a table have multiple primary indexes in progress openedge

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Can a table have multiple primary indexes in progress open edge.

Answer (score 1):

No - each table (and temp-table) has one and only one primary index.

This is also true for tables with "no" indexes defined for it - the db engine will make an index (based on recid?) for tables like that.

There is nothing very special about the designation "primary".  It is a potential tie-breaker used when other index selection rules result in multiple possible index choices -- if everything else is equal the "primary" index will be used.  It is also the default index used when various utilities are run.  But beyond that there is no magic associated with the "primary" attribute.

Comment: Yes, the index made by db engine is based on recid

Comment: ...but you can have a large number of secondary indices all your query needs!

Answer (score 0):

No. Each table can have only one primary index.

Answer (score 0):

A table can have multiple unique indexes, though. A primary index usually is (and should be) unique, but this is not enforced.
(Just in case there is confusion about primary and unique indexes.)